# Custom validation message for a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this select input field where I want to validate its selected field using JavaScript - and then show a html5 error message (and make its border red) if "01" is selected in the select input field. How can I accomplish this. Right now nothing happens if I select "01". The code can be tried here:

http://jsbin.com/wonuwo/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<form id="myForm">
<select name="cardexpiremonthPayment" id="cardexpiremonthPayment" title="Du skal vælge den udløbsmåned som optræder på forsiden af dit betalingskort" oninvalid="Please select Accused Name" onchange="checkValid(this)" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Vælg måned</option>
                                    <option value="01">01 - Januar</option>
                                    <option value="02">02 - Februar</option>
                                    <option value="03">03 - Marts</option>
                                    <option value="04">04 - April</option>
                                    <option value="05">05 - Maj</option>
                                    <option value="06">06 - Juni</option>
                                    <option value="07">07 - Juli</option>
                                    <option value="08">08 - August</option>
                                    <option value="09">09 - September</option>
                                    <option value="10">10 - Oktober</option>
                                    <option value="11">11 - November</option>
                                    <option value="12">12 - December</option>
                                </select>  

</form>
<script>
    function checkValid(input) {

        if (input.value == "01") {
            input.setCustomValidity("You're having too much fun!");
        } else {
             input.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This is interesting. Mozilla's own demo for CustomValidity doesn't seem to work - https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3146/constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery ::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#cardexpiremonthPayment" ).change(function() {
    alert($("#cardexpiremonthPayment option:selected").text());
    if($("#cardexpiremonthPayment option:selected").text() == '01 - Januar'){
      alert("Gotcha");
      $(this).css('background','rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)');
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I modyfide your code, so this will work:

```js
function checkValid(input) {

  if (input.value == "01") {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.border = "5px solid red" ;
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "";
          
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.border = "none" ;
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<select name="cardexpiremonthPayment" id="cardexpiremonthPayment" title="Du skal vælge den udløbsmåned som optræder på forsiden af dit betalingskort" oninvalid="Please select Accused Name" onchange="checkValid(this)" required>
                                    <option value="" selected="">Vælg måned</option>
                                    <option value="01">01 - Januar</option>
                                    <option value="02">02 - Februar</option>
                                    <option value="03">03 - Marts</option>
                                    <option value="04">04 - April</option>
                                    <option value="05">05 - Maj</option>
                                    <option value="06">06 - Juni</option>
                                    <option value="07">07 - Juli</option>
                                    <option value="08">08 - August</option>
                                    <option value="09">09 - September</option>
                                    <option value="10">10 - Oktober</option>
                                    <option value="11">11 - November</option>
                                    <option value="12">12 - December</option>
                                </select>  

</form>
<br/>

<div id="error" style="border: 1px solid red; display: none" >
  You're having too much fun!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change  the html code as this

```
   <select name="cardexpiremonthPayment" id="cardexpiremonthPayment" title="Du skal vælge den udløbsmåned som optræder på forsiden af dit betalingskort" oninvalid="Please select Accused Name" onchange="checkValid(value)" required>
```

value must be sent to the js function.you pass the object.It is the case.